# glibc : Test if lib as DF_1_NODELETE flag or if lib has unique symbol

Tags: c++, unique, glibc, dlopen

I'm using dlopen / dlclose to load lib with glibc 2.21.

Is there a C++ call to check a lib as a DF_1_NODELETE flag set ?
readelf seems to be able to do it.

or at least if a lib has unique symbol defined in it ?
nm is definitely able to do it.

ideally i would like something like :

```
CloseLib( libHandle lib)
{
  if( checkIfLibIsClosable(lib) )
  {
     dlclose(lib)
  }
}
```

This is in order to avoid calling dlclose on lib with DF_1_NODELETE flag, as calling it will fails with an assert error :

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 764: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

which is caused by DF_1_NODELETE flag set in dl-close.c:762, The flag is set in dl-lookup.c:332

Info about DF_1_NODELETE flag and unique symbol :

[DF_1_NODELETE](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2015-05/msg00810.html)

[Unique Symbol](https://www.redhat.com/archives/posix-c++-wg/2009-August/msg00002.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is in order to avoid calling dlclose on lib with DF_1_NODELETE flag, as calling it will fails with an assert error :

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 764: _dl_close: \
  Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

If calling `dlclose` on such a library causes above assertion, that is a bug in GLIBC and you should report it in [glibc bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=glibc).

As for detecting whether the `DF_1_NODELETE` (or any other) flag, yes you can do it by `read`ing the `Elf{32,64}_Ehdr` from the start of the library, then reading `Elf{32,64}_Phdr`s from `.e_phoff` offset until you find one with `.p_type == PT_DYNAMIC`, then reading `Elf{32,64}_Dyn`s from its  `.p_offset` until you find one with `.d_type == DT_FLAGS`, and finally checking whether its `.d_un.d_val & DF_1_NODELETE` is non-zero.

Comment: I've sent an mail on libc ml, w'll see. About your detection method, it seems doable, but if it is a bug, not necessary.