# "Unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x9" error on android gomobile

Tags: java, android, cordova, go, gomobile

What I got going on in the project is a Cordova project that uses gradle to build. I created an android plugin that calls the Go script in the form of an `.aar`. All works with the simple `hello world.go` `.aar`. So I know that everything works. But adding in the `selphyprint.aar` it crashes with `"Unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x9"`  error in adb logcat.

It's up at https://github.com/pbdesign/selphy. The full project is at https://github.com/pbdesign/printproject with an installable apk in the android folder of the `com.photobooth` project directory.

If you have any ideas, I found some similar error messages that are connected to android linker but don't know if they are related. Also any ideas on how to debug such an error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual full answer, but as a hint, DT_FLAGS_1 is a Binutils custom dynamic section entry (see the [ELF standard](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf)).

These are produce by Binutils ld during link.

The 0x8 bit in particular is defined as:

```
#define DF_1_NODELETE 0x00000008
```

inside include/elf/common.h in Binutils 2.29.1.

I would then try to determine from Binutils source / docs what `DF_1_NODELETE` does to understand what is happening.

That flag is also mentioned at: [glibc : Test if lib as DF_1_NODELETE flag or if lib has unique symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826309/glibc-test-if-lib-as-df-1-nodelete-flag-or-if-lib-has-unique-symbol)